# parentheses needed in R data.table j clause when using "with = FALSE"?

Tags: r, data.table

When selecting columns using a logical index vector different behavior occurs depending on the actual values in the index vector. For a data.table x with columns "a" and "b"

```
x[, !c(FALSE, FALSE), with = FALSE]
```

returns a Null data.table, whereas enclosing the (negated) index vector in parenthesis

```
x[, (!c(FALSE, FALSE)), with = FALSE]
```

returns columns "a" and "b" as expected.

When at least one element in the index vector is true, the parenthesis are not needed though. For example

```
x[, !c(FALSE, TRUE), with = FALSE]
```

returns column "a" as expected. See also the complete console output of the test script below.

Is this a bug or intended behavior? If the latter, can someone explain why?

```
require(data.table)
x <- data.table(a = c(1,2), b = c(10,20))
x
#    a  b
# 1: 1 10
# 2: 2 20

# doesn't work, returns Null data.table
x[, !c(FALSE, FALSE), with = FALSE]
# Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)

# works with paratheses, returns both columns
x[, (!c(FALSE, FALSE)), with = FALSE]
#    a  b
# 1: 1 10
# 2: 2 20

# works, returns first column
x[, !c(FALSE, TRUE), with = FALSE]
#    a
# 1: 1
# 2: 2

# works, returns second column
x[, !c(TRUE, FALSE), with = FALSE]
#   b
# 1: 10
# 2: 20

# works, returns both columns
x[, c(TRUE, TRUE), with = FALSE]
#    a  b
# 1: 1 10
# 2: 2 20
```

Comment: Please use `sessionInfo()` to indicate which version of `data.table` you are using.

Comment: data.table_1.9.6 rj_2.0.4-2

Comment: Also seeing this on 1.9.7. A more realistic example, to me, would be `x[, !sapply(x, is.character), with = FALSE]`

Comment: agreed. i constructed this minimal example because I initially thought it might have something to do with having a function call in the j clause, but that is not the case.

Comment: @Frank, is it required to pass column where we execute the condition ?  `x[, b = !sapply(x, is.character), with = FALSE]`.

Comment: @user5 No. What's happening there (I think) is that the `b` is being matched with the argument `by`. See `?"[.data.table"`